# Hide an object if it lies beyond some point (as seen from camera perspective)

Tags: javascript, three.js

Let cube be a `THREE.Mesh` added to the scene space.

```
cube.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );
scene.add( cube );
```

After rotating the scene with the mouse, I would like to **hide the cube object if its position, as seen from the current camera's position, lies beyond the scene space origin** at `(0,0,0)`. I guess where I stumble is: How can I transform the scene space coordinates to get the according coordinates from the camera perspective?

**Add-on**

As a novice to 3D I probably lack the proper "space"-vocabulary to describe the situtation. Some terminological clarification would be highly welcome as an add-on :)

**Update 2015-01-30**

*An improved explanation of what I want*: Using the frustum-far-analogy from [gaitat's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220565/hide-an-object-if-it-lies-beyond-some-point-as-seen-from-camera-perspective?noredirect=1#comment44804517_28220565), we may think of the above task as identifying all objects that lie beyond an imaginary frustum plane that passes through the red point. Now I want to identify all point that lie beyond that plane given that point, which in my case is (0,0,0).

[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear (to me). What do you mean when you say "... beyond the scene space origin at (0,0,0)". The camera definition takes a near and a far plane. Objects beyond the far plane are not visible. You can find a very good explanation (with a lot of math) at http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html and http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

Comment: @gaitat This basically does what I want except that I need to test for each object if it lies beyond the far frustum plane, as some objects must not be hidden. For completeness the code for gaitat's solution: `camera.far = camera.position.distanceTo(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)); camera.updateProjectionMatrix();`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an opaque plane that is perpendicular to the camera. Then anything behind it will be hidden. Based on [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330531/three-js-from-plane-orthogonal-vector-to-plane-rotation-matrix?answertab=active#tab-top), you could use the myPlane.lookAt() function to look at the camera's position and thereby make it perpendicular to the camera.

Comment: a) Can I do that virtually, i.e. without actually changing what the user sees?, b) would you mind to briefly outline how can I do that programmatically? :) TIA

Comment: My original answer wasn't great. I've rewritten it.