# three.js: GridHelper makes non standard grid?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have [been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330531/three-js-from-plane-orthogonal-vector-to-plane-rotation-matrix) that the standard normal vector for geometries in three.js is `(0, 0, 1)`.

However, when I make an instance of the GridHelper constructor, it makes a plane that is spanned by the X and Z axis. Such a plane has a normal vector of `(0, 1, 0)`.

This can be seen by this screenshot, showing the vertices arry of the geometry of my GridHelper:

[image]

and it is confirmed by visual inspection:

[image]

This is how I instantiate my GridHelper:

```
var myGridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 20);
```

*How come GridHelper does not comply with the standard normal vector?*

If this feature/bug is not going to change:
Can I solve it by always initiating my GridHelper instances with this code:

```
var standardPlaneNormal   = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
var GridHelperPlaneNormal = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
var quaternion  = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(standardPlaneNormal, GridHelperPlaneNormal);
var myGridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 20);
myGridHelper.rotation.setFromQuaternion(quaternion);
```

?

Comment: Can you solve what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: See this post: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 in default Threejs positive Y is "up"

Comment: @WestLangley
I want things to be rotated according to my expectations.. :). When I create a quaternion with a start vector and an end vector, the quaternion should rotate according to these. Now, if I feed `(0, 0, 1)` as the start vector, it won't do so.
My suggestion to add an extra quaternion rotation to compensate for this, was misguided. I can simply feed the alternative (or the true?) standard vector `(0, 1, 0)` as the start vector to `quaternion.setFromUnitVectors()`.
That makes things rotate according to my expectations :)

Comment: [I'm pretty sure 'up' is `(0, 1, 0)` now.](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.DefaultUp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the `lookAt()` method with `GridHelper`, you need to rotate the grid geometry so the grid lies in the XY-plane, instead of the XZ-plane. Once you do that, `lookAt()` will work as expected.

```
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 10, 2 );

grid.geometry.rotateX( Math.PI / 2 );

var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1 );
grid.lookAt( vector );

scene.add( grid );
```

three.js r.76

Comment: Is this because the standard vector is (0, 0, 1), and `lookAt` therefore expects things (planes) to lie in the XY.plane?

Comment: It is because `lookAt()` rotates the object so the object's local positive z-axis points in the desired direction. You need to orient your geometry so it is "looking" up the positive z-axis by default. If your object was an car, for example, you would orient the geometry so the car is facing the positive z-axis. Then `lookAt()` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If using `react-three-fiber`, the equivalent solution is:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'

...

<gridHelper
  args={[10, 2]}
  rotation={new THREE.Euler(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0, 'XYZ')}
/>
```

You must use the `rotation` property instead of the `rotateX` and `lookAt` methods. This is because `react-three-fiber`'s framework abstracts away all methods into the react render process, so that you can indicate values declaratively instead. See the `react-three-fiber` [docs](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/how-it-works) for more info.